# Unable to understand a disassembling of a function

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I've disassembled the following simple function into this And i'm failing to understand a few things. I'd be glad if people could help me out

This is the function i'm disassembling:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c){

    int t = 4;
    int t2 = 5;
    int t6 = 6;

    t = b;
    t2 = c;


    return (a *= t6);   
}
```

I invoked it from main function with the following parameters:

```
foo(2,3,4);
```

And this is what the function has been disassembled into:

```
.text:004013BE ; _DWORD __cdecl foo(int, int, int)
.text:004013BE                 public __Z3fooiii
.text:004013BE __Z3fooiii      proc near               ; CODE XREF: _main+2Dp
.text:004013BE                                         ; _main+5Cp
.text:004013BE
.text:004013BE var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:004013BE var_8           = dword ptr -8
.text:004013BE var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:004013BE arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:004013BE arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:004013BE arg_8           = dword ptr  10h
.text:004013BE
.text:004013BE                 push    ebp
.text:004013BF                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:004013C1                 sub     esp, 10h
.text:004013C4                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 4
.text:004013CB                 mov     [ebp+var_8], 5
.text:004013D2                 mov     [ebp+var_C], 6
.text:004013D9                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_4]
.text:004013DC                 mov     [ebp+var_4], eax
.text:004013DF                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_8]
.text:004013E2                 mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
.text:004013E5                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:004013E8                 imul    eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:004013EC                 mov     [ebp+arg_0], eax
.text:004013EF                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
.text:004013F2                 leave
.text:004013F3                 retn
.text:004013F3 __Z3fooiii      endp
```

- When loading the local variables of the function
  (var_c, var_8, var_4) the ESP pointer is substracted by 10h, 16 in decimal, every variable within our stack memory is **four bytes**, and I have three local variables - hence the ESP pointer should be substracted by 12 ( 0Ch ), why does it get substracted by 16?

**( .text:004013C1                 sub     esp, 10h )**

- In which point the return address of the procedure is saved?, also what about the old ESP?, when is that saved?

Comment: The snippet is correct, a 4-byte variable reads from 0 to 3, so the last variable reads from 0Ch to 10h.

Comment: That still doesn't make since, at the begining of the stack frame ebp and esp points at the same address, for examle lets say that adress is 0x48h, as the stack goes downwards, first variable would be (0x48h to 0x44h) second variable would be (0x44h to 0x40h) third variable would be (0x40h to 0x3Ch). what happens from (0x3Ch to 0x38h)?

Comment: You forgot the return address  is on top of the stack aka `[esp]`.

Comment: Again, that still doesn't make sense as the return address resides above the EBP ( above the previous base pointer that is above the current EBP )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> sub     esp, 10h
> ```

I wouldn't worry to much about this. Though only 12 bytes are needed for these local variables, the compiler might have its reason to always allocate in steps of 16 bytes.

> In which point the return address of the procedure is saved?

This resides at [ebp+4]

> also what about the old ESP?, when is that saved?

The `leave` instruction will mov `EBP` into `ESP`, thus restoring the stack pointer.

---

```
mov     [ebp+arg_0], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
```

I would be more worried by these superfluous codes. The result already is in `EAX`. Why move it around like that?

Comment: I agree, but that's the compiler's architecture unfortunately I wont understand that, anyways after disassembling many similar programs i've understood that Indeed that is part of the memory allocated to the current stack frame, anyways thanks

Comment: Actually this could be used as the security cookie, not sure.